# seperate product listing page into blocks and get content from different phtml file

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm in a product listing page `list.phtml`, i have overwritten template file adding another view. As this file looks mess(also more lines of codes), i want to break down this file into different phtml file.

Here is what i want to achieve.

```
<?php 
    if ($this->getMode() == 'newview'):
        //New added view
        //Get this part from another phtml file
   elseif($this->getMode() == 'grid'):
        //Grid view
        //Get this part from another phtml file
   else:
        //List view
        //Get this part from another phtml file
   endif;
?>
```

And obviously the product data `$_productCollection`,`$_attributes` and so on needs to be accessible form the separated file.

i have overwritten the product listing page(file) from layout file like this

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="product_list">
         <action method="setTemplate">
             <template>newview/catalog/product/customlist.phtml</template>
         </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="product_list_toolbar">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>newview/catalog/product/list/customtoolbar.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
<catalog_category_layered>
    //Same content as above.
</catalog_category_layered>
```

I am wondering as, i'm already inside a condition, is it possible to manage those parts from different file.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways you can do this is by passing the information you require in to the child blocks. For example

```
<?php

if ($this->getMode() == 'newview'):
    $this->getChild('newview')->setProductCollection($_productCollection);
    echo $this->getChildHtml();
endif;
```

You can call multiple sets one after the other.

To enable this you will need to declare your new blocks as children of the product_list. Something similar to following in your own theme layout file.

```
<reference name="product_list">
    <block type="core/template" name="newview" template="catalog/product/list/newview.phtml" />
</reference>
```

You can find examples of this inside magento. Specifically there is one in app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/view.phtml

on line 43/44 (checked in v1.9.2.1)

**Edit** Make sure you add your child blocks first otherwise you will get the fatal error as in the comments.

Regards,
Andy

Comment: It says `Fatal error: Call to a member function setProductCollection() on a non-object` and i guess it's `echo $this->getChildHtml('newview');` on above code.

Comment: Make sure you add your child blocks first. I will edit it in.